# OpenSSL 1.1.0: HMAC_CTX must now be allocated, why?

Tags: c, openssl

Checking the changes in recent OpenSSL releases, I now noticed that the HMAC_CTX structure *must* be allocated on the heap now. The headers only forward-declare it (in ossl_typ.h).

I wonder what the idea behind is. Given that heap allocated memory creates overhead, they must have a good reason for making the library slower. I just can't find the rationale behind it.

Anyone here know what made the developers decide to force allocation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen a lot of the OpenSSL structures going the same way.  I would think that it's because the implementers of OpenSSL want to "hide" the implementation state away from the users of the library.  That way the user can't "mess" with it in ways that the implementers don't want you to.  It also means that the implementers can change there implementation without the user code caring.  It's basically the "C" version of the [C++ PIMPL pattern](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/pimpl.html).

Comment: I guess that must be it. It's a lousy reason though, they could've just added some padding to their struct to be able to add fields in later releases without changing the size. Since it's still open source, you're not actually "hiding" anything.